# Is it possible for a function with a Kotlin coroutine to wait for completion and return to a Java class?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am working on a Java-based Android app. I want to start using Kotlin & coroutines for network-related work off the main thread, but I have run into an issue trying to figure out how to successfully handle a certain situation.

I have created a Kotlin file with a networking function which I plan to call in a Java class (a view model, which at this time needs to stay written in Java). The idea is that I want the networking function to modify and return a list back to the view model, and then allow the view model to proceed.

```
fun performNetworking(
    data: MutableList<Data>
): MutableList<Data> {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        data.forEach {
            // modify each element in the list
        }
    }
    return data
}
```

Currently, I am calling it from the Java view model as such:

```
    public void modifyData(List<Data> data) {
        List<Data> modifiedData = NetworkingKt.performNetworking(data);
        performMoreThings(modifiedData);
    }
```

With this implementation, `performMoreThings()` triggers as if none of the Data in the list was modified. Through debugging, I discovered that before the coroutine scope can do anything, the conclusion of `performMoreThings()` is reached with the unmodified Data list.

Therefore, I am wondering if there is a way to have the code wait for the coroutine scope's work to complete before returning the Data list to the Java view model (without locking up the primary thread and preventing the user from interacting with the app)? Or am I misunderstanding the abilities, purposes, and implementations of coroutines and this is not possible? Would I have to pass in a reference to the view model and have it call a continuation method once the coroutine is complete, much as I would do with AsyncTask's in its `onPostExecute()`?

Comment: Why not have `performNetworking()` be a `suspend fun`? You can use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` to say that the work in `performNetworking()` is done on suitable threads. Then, `modifyData` can use `viewModelScope` (or some other suitable `CoroutineScope`) to call `performNetworking()` and consume the result.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm not sure if you noticed, but `modifyData()` is a Java method, not Kotlin. It is not that easy to even launch a coroutine from Java (definitely possible, just not that trivial) and even if, we still have exactly the same problem OP described: we need to wait for the result, but waiting blocks the thread.

Comment: @broot: Ack! Yeah, I missed that. I am far too used to projects completing the Java -> Kotlin migration before tackling coroutines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Not because of limitations of coroutines, but the opposite - due to limitations of non-coroutine code. Your `modifyData()` is a regular, not-suspendable method, so it can't anyhow wait without blocking the thread. Suspend functions of Kotlin can do this, but Java methods can't.

You need to either invoke `modifyData()` from the background thread, so blocking won't be a problem or redesign `performNetworking()` to use one of classic techniques for dealing with asynchronous tasks, i.e. receive a callback or return a future:

```kotlin
fun performNetworking(
    data: MutableList<Data>
): CompletableFuture<MutableList<Data>> {
    return CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).future {
        data.forEach {
            // modify each element in the list
        }
        data
    }
}
```

```java
public void modifyData(List<Data> data) {
    NetworkingKt.performNetworking(data)
            .thenAccept(this::performMoreThings);
}
```

Comment: Returning a future is really interesting and it seems it would solve my issue. Our minimum API is 23, and I've learned it requires API 24. I'd imagine using a callback is my only option then. Question regardless: I cannot seem to call `.future` as you did in your example. Any idea why? Beyond this, if I were to convert my view model to Kotlin, my understanding is that I could make `performNetworking()` a `suspend fun` and then call it in the `ViewModelScope` and use `.async` and `await()` to accomplish what I wish to do. Does that align with your understanding?

Comment: As `CompletableFuture` was added in Java 8, `future()` is provided in a separate library: `kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8` - you need to add a dependency for it. Callbacks are also fine, And yes, when using coroutines we usually prefer to expose long-running operations as suspendable functions. However, if `modifyData()` is supposed to wait for `performNetworking()` then it makes more sense to make outer function also suspendable, then invoke `performNetworking()` directly.